# C# Tools that can be used to replace F12 command

Tags: visual-studio, go-to-definition

I was curious if there is/are tools that can be used to embed so the the function name in C# can have a link  in order to jump to its definition. In this case no need to right click and select 'go to definition' or F12. I was having hard time explaining what i meant. Hope someone can understand. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you talking about visual studio?

Comment: i forgot to mention that i am using visual studio 2008. ctrl+leftmouse is not working

Answer (score 2):

Ctrl + Left Mouse Button does the trick. Just Ctrl+Click the name of the function.
(assuming you are using Visual Studio with JetBrains ReSharper plugin).

Comment: Is this a feature of Visual Studio now, its been in R# for years, but I didnt know it wasn in VS by default.

Comment: I believe so. Though I am not quite sure. Let me check.

Comment: Actually it seems not. My VS Express 2012 does not have this shortcut. It might be a limitation to the Express series though.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand what you are after, but [ReSharper from JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) is an incredibly powerful addin to Visual Studio.

One of the functions is a replacement of the Go to Definition function.

Answer (score 1):

There is an extention in the visual studio gallery which allows Ctrl+Click Navigation

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/4b286b9c-4dd5-416b-b143-e31d36dc622b?SRC=VSIDE